# Bounding the tail of a series estimation of $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let $a\in[1,\infty)$. I'm trying to bound the (absolute value of the) following sum from above:

$\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^k}{k!}\right)(a-a^2)+\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}a^j\right)(a^2-a)$

It seems clear that this sum goes to $0$ for any choice of $a$ in the range, but I would like to obtain a good estimate in terms of $n$.

The first part of the sum can be estimated as a tail of a Taylor series for the exponential function, so I'm looking for a way to get a handle on the second part.

**Question:** What is a reasonable way to estimate the second part of the sum, i.e. $\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}a^j\right)(a^2-a)$?

Comment: Perhaps use that $$\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}a^j=\frac{a^k-a}{a(a-1)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$S=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}a^j\right)(a^2-a)$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}a^j=\frac{a^k-a}{a^2-a }$$
$$S=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^k}{k!}(a^k-a)=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi a)^k}{k!}-a\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^k}{k!}$$
$$S=e^{2 \pi  a}\frac{ \Gamma (n+1)-\Gamma (n+1,2 a \pi )}{\Gamma (n+1)}- a e^{2 \pi }\frac{ \Gamma (n+1)-\Gamma (n+1,2 \pi )}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$
$$S=e^{2 \pi  a}\Bigg[1-\frac{\Gamma (n+1,2 a \pi )}{\Gamma (n+1)} \Bigg]-ae^{2 \pi  }\Bigg[1-\frac{\Gamma (n+1,2  \pi )}{\Gamma (n+1)} \Bigg]$$